# Where can I programmatically download SRTM_V4.1 data?

Tags: dem, srtm, topography, curl

SRTM v4 is an effort by the folks at CIAT-CSI to scrub, polish, and remove gaps in the raw SRTM data released by NASA (SRTM 3).

One userfriendly interface : http://dwtkns.com/srtm/ provides *srtm_xx_yy.zip* tiles of ~20Mo each.

[image]

The [CIAT-CSI](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/) project provides 3 zipped tiles (W, NE, SE) of ~1Go each. These files are behind a public password (see page), on box.com, which block programmatic download.

**Is there any mirror with these 3 big SRTM 4 files using a stable link ?** so I may use a `makefile` to let coworkers to programmatically download them via `curl` or alikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ok to manage 872 tiles which can be later on `unzip` and `gdal_merge`, then :

```
wget -r --no-parent --random-wait --timestamping -A.zip http://gis-lab.info/data/srtm-tif/
```

or

```
curl -L 'http://gis-lab.info/data/srtm-tif/srtm_[01-72]_[01-24].zip' -o 'SRTM_V41_#1_#2.zip'
```

Comment: Thanks! For the others: first option is not working (403 error), an adding a -f to the second option (curl -f -L [...]) allows to skip non existing files.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe offtopic, but please note this new release:

"November 20, 2013

[NASA SRTM V3.0](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/nasa_shuttle_radar_topography_mission_srtm_version_30_srtm_plus_product_release) has eliminated all voids with fill primarily from ASTER GDEM2 (Global Digital Elevation Model Version 2), and secondarily from USGS GMTED2010 - or USGS National Elevation Dataset (NED) for the United States (except Alaska) and northernmost Mexico."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download from the official website, you can:

```
curl -f -L 'http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRT-ZIP/SRTM_V41/SRTM_Data_GeoTiff/srtm_[01-72]_[01-24].zip' -o 'SRTM_V41_#1_#2.zip'
```

Manual interface is available here: http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp