# programmatic DEM downloads similar to landsat-util

Tags: dem, data

I recently discovered [landsat-util](http://landsat-util.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and was wondering if there was an equivalent command-line application for global elevation data, (for data around 1 arcsecond resolution, preferably geotiff) or if there is a particularly clean programmatic way of downloading this kind of data. So far i've only found [bulk downloads](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69270/where-can-i-programmatically-download-srtm-v4-1-data) (whereas i would only like to download relevant tiles since i will be downloading them mid-script) and the [NED](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37405/programmatically-download-seamless-ned-tiles) (which correct me if i'm wrong but I believe it only covers the US?)

I hope this isn't too similar to the linked queries.

Comment: You can get 3 arcsecond data from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/ - there is an easy URL relationship from long/lat to tile identifier which is easier to see on the website than to explain here. I don't think 1 arcsecond is globally available, but I'd be happy to be corrected.

Comment: You can download SRTM-X data with 30 m resolution. However, the earth was acquired in strips with gaps in between. More information here: http://www.dlr.de/eoc/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-5515/9214_read-17716/ (--> "Downloads" on the right side of the webpage). The data can be downloaded after registration in EOWEB http://eoweb.dlr.de:8080/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool from the [OTB](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org) applications to [download SRTM tiles](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu65.html) related to a set of images. Basically it reads image information, then download the related tiles from http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/ . This is an open source library in C++, so you can look in detail to the code if you want to know how it's done.

EDIT based on @Kersten's comment: SRTM used to be available at 90 everywhere except for the US where it was 30m. More and more SRTM tiles at ~30 meter resolution have been released recently to cover most parts of the World, biggest exception being the Middle East and Northern Africa.

ASTER DEM is a more precise alternative, but it suffers from large artefacts in some places, so use it carefully if you do.

Comment: SRTM 1 arc second (~30m) data has already been released for most parts of the globe (biggest exception is the middle east and parts of northern africa). Just check the [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) if you're region is available.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/187416/70317)

> You can download and clip a portion of the SRTM 30m DEM with one
>   command with the
>   [elevation](http://elevation.bopen.eu/en/stable/quickstart.html)
>   Python command line tool.
>
> Install it and perform the self check with:
>
> ```
> $ pip install elevation
> ```
>
> Check if you have all the dependencies installed (mainly GDAL tools):
>
> ```
> $ eio selfcheck
> ```
>
> Download and clip a portion of the SRTM 30m DEM giving bounding box as
>   WGS84 coordinates:
>
> ```
> $ eio clip -o Rome-DEM.tif --bounds 12.35 41.8 12.65 42
> ```